# multiple commands on mysqli query doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

if I write a query like this :

```
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
$conn -> query ("
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS for_search;
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS for_search
        (
          id INT,
          for_search TEXT
        );
");
$conn -> close();
```

it doesn't work but if i rewrite that like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
$conn -> query ("
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS for_search;
");    
$conn -> query ("
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS for_search
        (
          id INT,
          for_search TEXT
        );
");
$conn -> close();
```

it will work!
i want to know why i can't write multiple line queries in mysqli?

Answer (score 1):

in mysqli you should use `multi_query` to run several queries:

```
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
    $conn -> multi_query ("
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS for_search;
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS for_search
        (
          id INT AUTOINCREMENT,
          for_search TEXT
        );
    ");
    $conn -> close();
```